# PHP - Preg match to match URL

Tags: php, regex

I have the following URL format:

```
http://www.domain.com/admin/?i=page
```

And on sub-pages, this is the format:

```
http://www.domain.com/admin/?i=page&n=subpage
```

When echoing `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI];` I get the following:

```
/admin/?i=page
```

I am trying to show an `.active` class whenever the page is active like this:

```
if(preg_match ('#^/admin/?i=page', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])){echo "active";}
```

However, the `active` class isn't triggered. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is surprising how many people don't use error reporting, https://eval.in/460748. `Warning: preg_match(): No ending delimiter '#' found`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You forget the ending php delimiter.
2. You forget to escape `?`

   ```
   if(preg_match ('#^/admin/\?i=page#', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])){echo "active";}
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a delimiter in the end of the regular expression. Moreover , '?' should be escaped :

```
#^/admin/\?i=page#
```